# How do I evaluate a lisp expression in the replacement string when calling replace-match?

Tags: string, emacs

I am trying to format many rows of TAB delimited data of the form below

```
ID  Name    Duration    Start_Date  Finish_Date Predecessors    Successors  Resource_Group  Deadline    Constraint_Type
```

into a list of fields using the lisp code below.

```
(while (re-search-forward "\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)\t\\(.*\\)" nil t)
    (replace-match 
"* \\2
   :PROPERTIES:
   :task_id: \\1
   :duration: \\3
   :start: \\4
   :finish: \\5
   :predecessors: \\6
   :successors: \\7
   :resource_group: \\8
   :deadline: \\9
   :constraint_type: \\,(match-string 10)
   :END:"
nil nil))
```

The code was performing as expected until reaching the 10th back-referenced matched string.  I found a solution to back referencing groups greater than 9 is to use the lisp function (match-string 10).  When using replace-regexp interactively, lisp code in the replacement string is evaluated if it is preceded by '\,', and ./(match-string 10) does behave as I expect when replace-regexp is called interactively;

however, the \\,(match-string 10) in the above code block produces an error.  I've tried one, two, three, four, etc '\' but it either produces the same error or prints a literal string.  Does anyone know of a way to use this function or a way to reference a group number greater than 9?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should probably upvote your own chosen correct answer as well.

Comment: How do I upvote?  I'm new and couldn't find anything in the FAQ about how/why voting works.  Any tips on how this is supposed to work would help, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the `\DIGIT` sequence in the replacement string, which appears not to support numbers greater than 9, you can construct the replacement string yourself, explicitly.  Something like:

```
(replace-match
 (concat "* " (match-string 2) "\n"
         "   :PROPERTIES:\n"
         "   :task_id: "         (match-string 1)  "\n"
         "   :duration: "        (match-string 3)  "\n"
         "   :start: "           (match-string 4)  "\n"
         "   :finish: "          (match-string 5)  "\n"
         "   :predecessors: "    (match-string 6)  "\n"
         "   :successors: "      (match-string 7)  "\n"
         "   :resource_group: "  (match-string 8)  "\n"
         "   :deadline: "        (match-string 9)  "\n"
         "   :constraint_type: " (match-string 10) "\n"
         "   :END:")
 nil t)
```

Oh, and incidentally, the `\,(...)` construction is not supported by `replace-match`, only by `query-replace-regexp`.

EDIT: Also note that `\,(...)` does not simply go into the replacement string.  There is quite a lot of magic there.  To peek behind the curtains use <kbd>C-x ESC ESC</kbd> after `query-replace-regexp`.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked great, and thanks for pointing out that \,(...) is not supported by replace-match.